# Nginx in docker can't find cert files

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl-certificate

I generated certificates on my host machine, they are located in `/etc/letsencrypt`

Then, in my `docker-compose.yml` I have following configuration

```
  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    container_name: frontend
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    networks:
      - not-exposed
      - exposed
    volumes:
      - /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrpt
```

For testing purposes, I stopped at this point and I started container to see if I can access those files and they are inside my container

[image]

However, moving to my nginx `default.conf` file, I have following code there

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    server_name example.com;
    
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; 
}
```

Unfortunatelly, when I run `docker-compose up`, it fails with

> 2022/10/26 13:51:38 [emerg] 1#1: cannot load certificate
> "/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem": BIO_new_file()
> failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or
> directory:fopen('/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem','r')
> error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)

Any idea why? Like I mentioned, this file is there on container that holds nginx and my frontend, why it can't be opened?

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Just include the text itself in your question, formatted as a code sample.

Comment: But do note that you have a typo in your `docker-compose.yaml`: check the spelling of `letsencrypt` in your `volumes` configuration.